# How do I automatically resize GUI elements in AnyLogic?

Tags: user-interface, anylogic

When designing a GUI in most languages, you typically don't give exact dimensions for each component. Rather, you say how GUI components fit and size relative to each other. For example, Button1 should take up all the space Button2 and Button3 don't use; the TextPanel should fill as much space as it can; and the horizontal list of images should expand and shrink as the window expands and shrinks. In AnyLogic, I don't see any obvious way to do this, yet I need to develop models that work on multiple screen sizes. Is it possible to auto-scale GUI components in AnyLogic as it is in other languages? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct support for that as far as I know.
However, some of your requests can be achieved programmatically, i.e. by using the dynamic properties of your GUI elements.
There is the function getWindowWidth() (and height()) for experiments and you can set your button's width to equal that. With a bit of playing, you should be able to get your desired result.

cheers

Comment: It's too bad that I can't autosize things, but this will work. Thanks!